# Retrieve click data from Python Holoviews / Datashader

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash, holoviews, datashader

I'm coming from Python-Dash trying to achieve an interactive graphing functionality by creating a second graph using the click data of the first one. Similar to what can be found [here](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing)

I'm stuck in retrieving and correctly using the click data to potentially create a second graph.

Here is what I've tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade, dynspread
from holoviews import streams
import panel as pn 
import datashader as ds
hv.extension("bokeh")
packages=[np,pd, hv, pn, ds]
for i in packages: print(i.__name__, i.__version__)

#dummy data
N=1200
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': np.arange(0,N,1),
    'product' : [np.random.choice(['A', 'B']) for i in range(N)],
    'quantity' : np.random.randint(1,10,N),
    'price' : np.random.randint(50,100,N),
})
df.head(2)

def clicked_point(x, y):
    return pn.pane.Str('Click at %0.2f, %0.2f' % (x, y), width=200)

kdims = ['date', 'quantity']
vdims = ['product', 'quantity']
points  = hv.Points(df, kdims, vdims)

shaded = datashade(points)
spreaded = dynspread(shaded)
plot = spreaded.opts(tools=['hover','tap'])

stream = hv.streams.Tap(source=spreaded, x=np.nan, y=np.nan)
layout = pn.Row(plot, pn.bind(clicked_point, x=stream.param.x, y=stream.param.y))
layout
```

[image]

The problem is that it's unclear to me how to use the click data printed on right of the graph and/or the data available in the tooltip to, for example, go back to the original dataframe and filter it  based on these values. It would be nice to be able to do something like:

```
df2=df.loc[(df['date']==clicked_date) & (df['quantity']==clicked_quantity) ]
```

I'd appreciate any suggestion on this regard.

Best,

dll

Comment: Do you want to solve this using Dash? Because I do not see any dash code in your code.

Comment: Hey @Phoenix, thanks for your question. I know how to do it in Dash, it's also explained in the link.  But this time I want to take advantage of the datasahder aggregating capabilities.

Comment: It should be possible to do it the way you've started above, but HoloViews has an operation inspect_points designed just for this. You can see an example at https://examples.pyviz.org/ship_traffic .

Comment: BTW, HoloViews + Datashader + Plotly should work with Dash as well, but I'm not a Plotly user so I'm not sure what limitations there are compared to HoloViews + Datashader + Bokeh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this requires to create a function to filter the data based on the click data create a streams object in holoviews to capture the events data and then put them together in the table. Notice there could be multiple ways of approximating the x-y coordinates to actual points in the data. In this case, for instance, I just rounded up x and y coordinates:

```
def click_table(x,y):    
   if x  is None or y is None:
       df2=[]
   else:
       df2=table[round(x,0) , round(y,0)]
return df2 

stream = hv.streams.Tap(source=spreaded, x=np.nan, y=np.nan)
layout = pn.Row(plot, 
            pn.bind(clicked_point, x=stream.param.x, y=stream.param.y),
            pn.bind(click_table, x=stream.param.x, y=stream.param.y)
           )
layout
```